Question 29 from Chapter 3 of A first course to probability from Sheldon Ross ed. 10

Xiku Road has $n_1$, $n_2$, $n_3$, and $n_4$ houses with $1$, $2$, $3$, and $4$ occupants, respectively. Two random selection without replacement strategies are being contemplated to obtain a sample of the residents. In the first strategy, residents are selected with equal probability. In the second strategy, houses are first randomly selected and then residents from these houses are selected.
Work out, in terms of $n_1$, $n_2$, $n_3$, and $n_4$, the conditional probability of a resident from a $3$-occupant house being selected given that the first selection came from a $4$-occupant residence under both strategies.

My Approach
Let $H$ be no. of house and $R$ be no. Of residents.
$H = n_1 + n_2 + n_3 + n_4$
$R = n_1 + 2n_2 + 3n_3 + 4n_4$
S: Random resident chosen.
E: Resident chosen from 3-occupant house.
F: Resident chosen from 4-occupant house.
By first strategy:
$P(S) = \frac{1}{R}$
$P(E) = \frac{3n_3}{R}$
$P(F) = \frac{4n_4}{R}$
$P(E|F) = \frac{3n_3}{R-1}$
By second strategy:
$P(S) = \frac{n_1}{H} + \frac{n_2}{2H} + \frac{n_3}{3H} + \frac{n_4}{4H} $
$P(E) = \frac{n_3}{3H}$
$P(F) = \frac{n_4}{4H}$
$P(E|F) = \frac{n_3}{3H}$
I think after selecting $n_3$ houses it doesn't matter a resident from $n_4$ has already been selected because it becomes independent of that and for selection of houses is independent of resident selected.
Please verify my assumption.

What you have calculated for first strategy and your assumption are both correct but there is an error in your answer for strategy $2$.
In $2$nd strategy for a $3$ occupant house member to be chosen the chosen house should be a $3$ member house and if a $3$ member house is chosen the required probability becomes $1$ and if not chosen the probability becomes $0$.
So, by Bayes theorem,
$P(E\vert F)=\frac{n_3}H$

As the question asks for 3-occupant house then I think your answer is correct for P(E|F). But for P(S) by second strategy first we need the summation. If P(S) is same in both cases then summation should result to that. For first strategy writer had told that everyone have equal probability of being chosen.

@AbhishekSingh yes you are right about the P(S} part will correct it
